# Why instantiating an object is not runned until the object is used?

Tags: c#, memory-management, jit

In C# I have remarked that if I run the following code won't have any effect over my memory:

```
Console.WriteLine("press a key to allocate the memory");
Console.ReadKey();
double[] hudgeBunchOfMemory = new double[100000000];
Console.WriteLine("allocated");
Console.ReadKey();
```

But if I iterate through the array and use them, the allocation just runs, like in this sample:

```
Console.WriteLine("press a key to allocate the memory");
Console.ReadKey();
double[] hudgeBunchOfMemory = new double[100000000];
for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
    hudgeBunchOfMemory[i] = i + 1;
}
Console.WriteLine("allocated");
Console.ReadKey();
```

What generates this behavior?

**EDIT**

I have runed the code with Visual Studio 2012 in both release and debug modes, and I have remarked the memory changes with task manager, and it could be really simple observed the differences since it takes 800Mb of memory.

The most appropriate question regarding this behavior it is: Is the code executed, and the memory still not alocated, or it isn't executed at all, and avoided by the JIT compiler?

Comment: hint - the compiler is pretty smart.

Comment: Run it in Release and Debug mode and use an appropriate tool to measure memory. You provide non of the essential info here.

Comment: Correction: the runtime is pretty smart. The compiler, by design, is not. The compiler will happily emit code that would allocate all that memory. It does not optimise it away, and inspecting the generated CIL code will show that.

Comment: @hvd:  The 'runtime' is/has a second compiler.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, which typically gets the name "jitter", not "compiler". In the context of C#, "the compiler" pretty much exclusively means the compiler that turns C# code into CIL code.

Comment: I guess @hvd is pretty close to the answer! As I guess it is because of the JIT, but I am not sure, and I want a clarifcation.

Comment: @DanielA.White Not even close. This is the operating system refusing to reserve memory which isn't accessed. The allocation itself only provides a virtual address range to the process, but it's not mapped to / reserved in physical memory until accessed. Taskmanager in Windows per default only shows reserved, not virtual memory.

Comment: It is always better to use Process Explorer and enable Process Memory -> Virtual Size column. This will tell you the exact amount of Virtual Memory reserved. Task Manager shows the Virtual Paged Memory which is the amount of memory in RAM which means if your console application is paged out, it can be 0 too.

Comment: @GaneshR. if the cosole application is still active, it will not be paged.

Comment: Just download vmmap from SysInternals and then you can force page it out. Also if your Console App goes into the background and there is a memory pressure on the system, then too the Console App can be paged

Comment: @GaneshR. I meant in this test, the console application could not be paged, because it was active, but of course it can be paged.

Comment: Agreed. But the memory shown by Task manager is always less than the virtaul memory. Anyways for memory analysis, it is always recommended to look at Virtual Memory and Private Bytes for .NET

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statistic you are looking at, probably in Task Manager, is *working set*.  It measures the amount of physical memory your process use.  RAM.

```
   double[] hudgeBunchOfMemory = new double[100000000];
```

On a demand-paged virtual memory operating system like Windows (or Linux or OSX), that statement does **not** allocate RAM.  The CLR takes full advantage of the virtual memory feature of the OS, it allocates *address space*.  Just numbers to the processor, one each for every 4096 bytes of memory.

You can in fact see that allocation taking an effect, you have to add a column in Task Manager to see it.  Use View > Select Columns or right-click the column headers and select "Commit size".  Also pick "Page faults", gives more insight.

Now you see the difference in your first snippet.  After you press enter you see the Commit size column jump up.  The CLR has allocated the address space with VirtualAlloc() and ensured that the memory reservation is *committed*, it also allocated 800000000 bytes in the paging file.  You *do* see the working set go up a wee bit, RAM that's used to store the page table mapping entries that store those one-per-4096 bytes numbers.  And two pages (8192 bytes) that the CLR makes hot intentionally since it will assume you use those pages first.

You can now also see the effect that your second snippet has.  When you access the array elements then the pedal needs to meet the metal and you *do* need to have RAM allocated to store the array elements.  At a very low level, the instruction that writes the memory address causes a *page fault*.  That forces the OS to implement the *demand paged* feature, it has to allocate physical memory.  You now see both the working set and the page fault counters zip up.  Probably too fast for you to see them changing, modern machines have a lot of RAM.  It might not be when the OS has to fight to get the RAM and take it away from other processes, hard page faults are expensive.

Lots of wrong guesses in the comments, they ought to be addressed.  No, neither the compiler nor the jitter have any effect on this whatsoever.  This is purely OS behavior.  It behaves the same both in the Debug and Release build.  And even though you don't actually use the array in the 1st snippet, as you can tell from the Commit Size counter it does *not* get eliminated by the jitter optimizer.  It is conservative about any `new` statement and always assume its side-effects should be visible.